# How to find shortes palindrome subsequence in the char[]

Tags: c++, char, substring, palindrome

I am looking for the shortest palindrome in the char[]. How to do it beside taking every char and checking its surroundings chars what is giving `O(n^2)`?

Comment: The shortest palindrome is always of length 0...do you mean "the longest"?

Comment: A shortest palindrome would consist of the first character.

Comment: the question of what "shortest palindrome" means aside, why on earth do you want to optimize this? what does your **measurements** say?